# "Compress/Optimize" .less File

Tags: css, optimization, less

Is there a way to optimize a less File? We have 2-3k lines of CSS/LESS in a file, this get´s minified - fine.

But I noticed that some changes are in there twice. Is there an .less optimizer? Best case without minifiying so you can still read it as a human.

Comment: Are the exact selectors "in there twice", or is there duplication caused by the expansion of LESS into CSS? For example, a mixin will be expanded for each use (better option may be to use extend()).

Comment: Another way to reduce bloat is keeping away from vendor prefixing new attributes like `display:flex` and letting [autoprefixer](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix) do that for you while compiling.

Comment: The answer to your question is: "Yes, there's". The rest depends on various details missing in your Q. So voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: It would be the first one - selectors that are used twice.